# Is there any notation for all elements of a sequence coming from another set?

Tags: notation

Let $\{ A(\lambda, i) \}_{i=0}^{N-1}$ be a sequence denoted by $A(\lambda)$ and $B$ be a set. Is there any established notation to show that all elements of $A(\lambda)$ come from the set $B$ ? The notation should be between $A(\lambda)$ and $B$.

For example, I have created the following notation. Let us suppose $A(\lambda) \leftarrowtail B$ denotes 
$$
 A(\lambda, i) \in B \text{ for all } i \in \{0,\ldots,N-1 \}.
$$

Is there any already established notation to achieve this relationship?

Comment: What is $\lambda$?

Comment: @user18921 $\lambda \in \{0,\ldots,N-1\}$, where $N \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Okay, but I still don't get your notation. What does $\{A(λ,i)\}^{N−1}_i$ mean? If you could explain it using the concepts of "set" and "function" only, that would be great.

Comment: @user18921 $\{A(\lambda,i)\}_{i=0}^{N-1}$ represents a finite sequence $A(\lambda,0), A(\lambda,1), \ldots, A(\lambda,N-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use the strict subset notation $\subset$ Thus just have

$$A(\lambda)\subset B$$

Comment: $A(\lambda)$ is a sequence, and that is why, I don't think it can be a subset of a set. For example, I cannot write $A(\lambda) \subset \mathbf{R}$.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying I thought you probably meant something different but I thought id give it a try.  You want to say that set of elements is a subset but not the sequence itself right?

Comment: Yes you are right. I want a notation to describe that the set of elements of a sequence $A(\lambda)$ is a subset of $B$.

Comment: @AitAbd: I don't think there's a very precise notation for that, but I've seen exactly this (i.e. $\subseteq$) used to denote just that, even if it's a little imprecise. Alternatively, I've seen $A(\lambda)\in B^*$ where $*$ is supposed to denote an arbitrary product. Of course, if you know the length of the sequence, you can just say $A(\lambda)\in B^n$ or if you know it's finite $A(\lambda)\in B^{<\omega}$.